# Github can connect with ssh but can't clone repository

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to setup ssh for github on my second computer.
This computer already had an SSH key for work purposes so I made an extra SSH key especially for Github.

I don't know what is going on but at the moment I've added my public github SSH key to my github profile, I've registered the key to my ssh-agent and I can establish a connection with the github test connection

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

which returns this message:

> Hi **my github username**! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

So when I thought we were good to go, I wanted to clone my repo

```
git clone git@github.com:my-username/BAP24.git
```

and got this error instead..:

> Cloning into 'BAP24'...
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have no clue how to fix this issue and I'm done with it.
Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Can you show the commands you are using?

Comment: Commands are added!

Comment: Looks like you are not having sufficient permissions to access the git repository.

Comment: @AnkitJindal any ideas how to aquire them?

Comment: @Stef-Verniers only owner(s) of the repository can grant you access.